# mySQL move data into another table according to its state

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a Table (Booking) with 8 columns (date from, date to and some foreign keys) and two columns (deleted, completed) which determine the state of the booking.

Is it a good idea to move those booking rows which are completed into new Tables (deletedBookings and completedBookings) and remove those two columns or should I let them in the current Table and set the status with a Boolean.

Comment: No, it is not a good idea if the current system is working fine.

Comment: Does being deleted preclude the possibility of being completed (and/or vice versa)? Either way, your current setup sounds infinitely preferable to whatever you have in mind.

Comment: No a deleted booking means it got cancelled but we have to keep the record just in case there is a dispute so we know who made the booking and whose fault it is. And completed means that the booking is finished and the work is done we also have to keep those bookings for billing.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to create new tables with one column, it is not recommended to remove the columns and create new tables. According to the data warehouse design, you can have both the columns if they are not normalizes and either you can flag it or maintain the actual value.

Comment: No I also have more columns (date from, date to and about 6 foreign keys) and this two columns which determine the state right now and I want to know if it is better to remove those two state columns and move the row into another table if it is completed. Thanks

Comment: No, you can have then in the same table. No need to move in to separate table

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to have two tables called, say, `Current` and `History`.  Most queries would be against `Current`.  It would not need either of the flags you suggest, but `History` may have those flags do indicate why they are no longer in Current.

In a "normal" situation,

1. A row is added to `Current`.
2. Whatever manipulation is done there (for an 'active' booking).
3. That row is transactionally deleted from Current and added to History.  (Extra columns would be added/removed during this transfer.)

If you expect to purge "old" History rows, then consider using `PARTITIONing` on `History`, but not `Current`.

It would not be possible to have links from other tables into these two tables.  But the opposite is possible (for normalization, etc).

The two tables might have different indexes.  In general, open your mind to what differences between the two tables would be beneficial.